# Running multiple SQL files at once

Tags: bash, mysql, sql

I feel like I've run commands like the following in the past, but I'm getting an error trying it right now.  Maybe I'm just having a brainfart, and my syntax is off.

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < *.sql
```

What I expect this to do is run all the SQL files in the folder ordered alphanumerically.  However, I'm getting this error:

```
-bash: *.sql: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
cat *.sql | mysql -u root -p db_name
```